# WiX Custom Action failing to connect to DB When FIPS Policy is Enabled

Tags: c#, oracle, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB using WiX Custom action, Whenever FIPS Policy is 1(enabled) i am not able to Log in to Database.

I have tried to Ignore FIPS policy using App.config file, but it seems Custom action is ignoring it.

```
<runtime>
    <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
</runtime>.
```

Same solution when applied to console application works perfectly.
I Have also verified that CustomAction is reading Config files(I displayed Connection string from Config file using session.log).

I am using .Net 4.5.1 and Oracle. ManageddataAccess.dll.

Answer (score 0):

The Bug is in Oracle ManagedDataAcess.I switched to Unmanaged ODP.Net (Oracle.DataAcess.dll) and issue was solved.

For anyone else facing same issue, changing in config file will not help solve this issue.If you have to used Managed Driver for ODP use ODAC 12c release 3 or switch to unmanaged driver.

For Further reference

https://community.oracle.com/message/12738172#12738172
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3626561?start=0&tstart=0